# Uppgrading from Classic GA to Global site tag via GTM in Magento 1.8

Tags: magento-1.8, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

we are currently using Magento v1.8 and using the classic GA tracking. We have implement Google Tag manager and also upgraded to the new analytics using Global Site tag. However, the statistic that we see seems to be inaccurate. Could it be that this old Magento version does not support the new Global site tag?

Thanks for helping.

/confused

Answer (score 0):

From Magento Market place, I can see that the Google Tag Manager module is compatible with **Magento ver. 1.8**.

In fact it is compatible all the way to **ver. 1.5**.

Follow this link for more information: https://marketplace.magento.com/chapagain-chapagain-googletagmanager.html#product.info.details.support